# Could the Scotsman's sword harm Aku?

Tags: samurai-jack

A recurring character and ally of Jack, the Scotsman possesses a sword etched with magic runes that provide it with cutting power and the strength to resist being broken by Jack's blade (their first encounter was rather terse). Like Jack the Scotsman also has a bounty placed on his head by Aku though whatever crimes he might have committed are unclear.

Has it ever been established whether or not Aku could be slain by the Scotsman's blade?

Comment: Aku is too mysterious to have a weakness other than Jack's sword. As far as I remember, it was never told in the show that he had any other achilles' heel.

Comment: +1 just for being a Samurai Jack question!

Answer (score 10):

## We don't know, maybe.

We know very little of the Scotsman from three TV series,  except that his blade held its own when he and Jack clashed in their first meeting, and that it has magical runes, which make it similarly powerful to Jack's

[[image: The Scotsman's Sword's Runes][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kpmug.jpg)

The other point that must be made is that in the show, from what I remember, while magic (both items and forces) harms Aku, it is only Jack's sword that appears to cause any damage that can't be regenerated almost instantly.

Quoting the wiki:

> he can be destroyed by the strength and purity of a human's (and likely any other living creature) spirit, as stated by Vishnu. Jack's katana is virtually the only item which can cause Aku damage that he cannot instantly regenerate from

It's possible the Scotsman's Sword would do the same, vicious temporary damage, but with no long lasting effect. Unless, perhaps, he is also pure of spirit (caveat,  I haven't seen the episode with Vishnu, so I don't have specifics about this purity).

So the only reasonable answer is,  **maybe**

Answer (score 3):

Although the Scotsman sword is "magical" and has "magical" rune stones. Jacks sword was made by high skyfathers Odin, Ra,and Vishnu. The Scottsmans sword can boast no such claims. Could it harm Aku? Maybe. Has it? No. Can Jacks sword harm Aku? Yes. Has it? Yes. Based off of feats and displayed info and history: Jacks sword>Scotsman sword.

Comment: I should point we've yet to hear the origins of the scotsman's blade, it very will could share the pedigree of Jack's katana- for all we know just possessing it is the reason Aku wants him dead (reruns confirm Aku put the bounty on the scotsman) in the first place.

Comment: I suppose the Scotsman will have to wait for his turn in Samurai Scott, against the evil Akew.